# How to ignore gems when running rake doc:rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rdoc

When I run `rake doc:rails` it fails with an error don't know how to build task `/Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@rails3/gems/rspec-activemodel-mocks-1.0.1/README.rdoc`

This appears then that it is trying to generate docs for the gems as well as my app.  Is there a way to have the task skip gems?

Comment: You are generating the documentation of rails. It's the same as the [Rails API Website](http://api.rubyonrails.org/). If you want to generate the docs for your app you should use `rake doc:app`. If you want to generate the Rails API than there is unfortunately no parameter to skip this. But could you add the full trace?

Comment: Oy vey! Thanks for correcting me on the task there; that did the trick. Now I'm feeling a bit sheepish.